# Finding minimum in teradata if values can be null also

Tags: case, teradata, minimum

I want to find minimum of six values in teradata. Following is the logic I am using but it fails when there is a null value in either of the fields. I would appreciate your help on this. Thanks in advance.

```
CASE WHEN event.A1 <= event.A2 and event.A1 <= event.A3 and event.A1 <= event.A4 and event.A1
 <= event.A5 and event.A1 <= event.A6 THEN event.A1
     WHEN event.A2 <= event.A3 and event.A2 <= event.A4 and event.A2 <= event.A
WAITING_PICKUP_NOTELEFT and event.A2 <= event.A6 THEN event.A2
     WHEN event.A3 <= event.A4 and event.A3 <= event.A5 and event.EXC_DELI
VERY_ATTEMPT <= event.A6 THEN event.A3
     WHEN event.A4 <= event.A5 and event.A4 <= event.A6 THEN event.EXC_DELIVER
Y_ATT_NOTE
     WHEN event.A5 <= event.A6 THEN event.A5
     ELSE coalesce(event.A6,event.A5,event.A4,event.A3,event.A2,ev
ent.A1) END AS ZZZ
```

Comment: Easiest way, but lots of text: `CASE WHEN event.A1 IS NOT NULL AND (event.A1 <= event.A2 OR event.A2 IS NULL) AND ...`

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd use a derived table to handle all the null logic one time, and then select from that.  Something like:

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN t1.a1 <= t1.a2 and t1.a1 <= t1.a3...

FROM
  (Select 
   coalesce(event.A1,0), --don't know what the data type is, replace accordingly
   coalesce(event.A2,0),
...) t1
```

It's still kind of ugly, but I think it will still be simpler.

EDIT:
I may be oversimplifying, but if you're on TD 14, you could look into the `LEAST` function:

> SELECT LEAST(event.a1,event.a2,event.a3,...)